# JSF bean is not interpreted on the *.xhtml page

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-boot

I am trying to configure JSF/primefaces with Spring boot in my maven project. I am following this example https://github.com/stephanrauh/JSF-on-Spring-Boot which works good.

Issue: **when Application is running, the JSF views are shown without data from the back-end**.

Here is my *.java classes:

```
@Configuration
public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ServletContextAware {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    }
}
```

HelloBean class:

```
@ManagedBean(value = "helloBean")
@ViewScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    private String hello = "Hello from PrimeFaces and Spring Boot!";

    public String getHello() {
        return hello;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println(hello);
    }
}
```

index.xhtml file:

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ng="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:prime="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title>#{menuController.title}</title>
        <style>
        body {font-size:12px; }
</style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <prime:panel header="What do you see here?" >
                <div style="height:50px">
                    This is a simple PrimeFaces 5 project running on Spring Boot 1.1.4.
                </div>
            </prime:panel>
            <prime:panel header="JSF 2.2 Bean Access">
                #{helloBean.hello}
            </prime:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Could anyone tell me why **helloBean** is not displayed on index.xhtml ?

Comment: Looking into the configurations, you are trying to register `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` which is a Spring MVC artifact (taking incoming requests and delegates processing of those requests to one of matching handlers which is supposed to be present at the said location). You cannot use use it while using JSF. I do not see such a recommendation in the project on GitHub.

Comment: As @Tiny says, there's no need of a `Dispatcher` servlet in pure JSF applications. Also, there's some problem when using Spring boot, that you need to declare the JSF servlet twice in order to get it set up, either in web.xml and java config. That's a problem I've suffered in all my JSF + Spring boot projects...

Comment: Finally I have found solution to my issue.The problem was in HelloBean.class. I have used incorrect import -  import javax.annotation.ManagedBean instead of import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found solution to my issue.The problem was in HelloBean.class. I have used incorrect import -  import javax.annotation.ManagedBean instead of import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

Comment: please mark this as the selected answer if this already solved your question

Answer (score 1):

I've made a different configuration to run Spring Boot + JSF. I think it is simpler. Check it out:

faces-config.xml

```
<application>       
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver> 
</application>

<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingPhaseListenerMulticaster</phase-listener>
</lifecyle>
```

MyApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {           
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApp.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

From Spring Boot 1.2 and above you can set the JSF parameters in the application.properties file, as below:

```
### JSF CONFIGS ###
server.context_parameters.com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration=true
```

The Managed Bean of course. Remember not to use the javax.faces.bean package for the bean annotations

MyBean.java

```
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;    

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    public String getHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

And finally, the view:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="views/templates/basic_template.xhtml"
>

<ui:define name="body_content">
    <p:panel header="JSF 2.2 Bean Access">
        <h:outputText value="#{myBean.hello}" />
    </p:panel>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```